# Heroku app is asleep even when receiving traffic and not waking up

Tags: java, heroku, telegram-bot

I have an app (Telegram Bot actually) deployed to heroku using web dynos.

I found this information in official heroku website:

> If an app has a free web dyno, and that dyno receives no web traffic in a 30-minute period, it will sleep.

> If a sleeping web dyno receives web traffic, it will become active again after a short delay (assuming your account has free dyno hours available

But this case doesn't work for me. My application works only 25-35 minutes and goes to 'asleep mode' and(!) doesn't want to wake up. Only `heroku restart` helps.

I tested it like this:

- Start app
- Keep sending messages to my Telegram bot every 5 minutes (so traffic incoming)
- App is running and keep responding
- I fall into the gap in which the application stops responding
- Keep sending messages but app is still silent

After this I went to my Heroku Dashboard and noticed that app is on 'asleep mode' (with zzz icon). Okay, let's check logs `heroku logs --source app`.

What can I see there? Almost nothing. No errors, no crashes, successful logged last message. Also my app is using MongoDB, and last log message is:

```
2020-07-03T14:49:20 [extShutdownHook] org.mongodb.driver.connection: Closed connection [
connectionId{localValue:4, serverValue:129573}] to botcluster-shard-00-01-aeqgg.mongodb.net:27017 because the pool has been closed.
```

So my connection to database was closed before the application stopped.

In addition I decided to write service class which will ping Google's webpage every 5 minutes.

```
public class PingTaskService {

    @Value("${pingtask.url}")
    private String url;

    @Scheduled(fixedRateString = "${pingtask.period}")
    public void keepAlive() {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(getUrl());
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            connection.disconnect();
            log.info("Ping {}, OK: response code {}", url.getHost(), connection.getResponseCode());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("Ping FAILED");
        }
    }
}
```

Logs:

```
2020-07-03T14:46:47 [scheduling-1] ru.miroha.service.PingTaskService: Ping www.google.com, OK: response code 200
```

3 minutes between last ping and hibernation.

I conclude that heroku just does not consider all of the above actions as web traffic.

What should I do to keep my app alive?

Comment: what type of dyno are you using? web, worker or one-off! and is it a free dyno?

Comment: Like I said in the post: free web dyno.

Comment: I guess it happens because I'm using LongPolling bot instead of WebHook bot. LongPolling should use worker dyno, WebHook should use web dyno. I'll try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.

I had 2 options:

1. Switch from LongPolling (getUpdates method) to WebHook and configure Controller.
2. Rewrite my ping task service.

I chose 2nd option because didn't want to rewrite my bot business logic.

Instead of ping google I started to ping url for my app provided by heroku.
`https://example.herokuapp.com/`
Now my app doesn't go into sleep mode, because every 10 minutes I literally send request "from my app to my app".

Comment: It's good that you found such kind of "solution".But unfortunately, it's quite an inefficient way, especially if you are using free Heroku dynos. When you ping your app every 10 minutes you are exhausting your free dyno hours quite extensively and eventually, you will waste them all...
Please check this out (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours)
So I kindly recommend you switch to long pooling if you would like to be in the boundaries of the free plan.